# Ozzie Inputformat MapReduce API

Tags: oozie

I'm trying to create an OOZIE job with a custom inputformat. I am using the new API and have set :

```
  <property>
        <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
         <value>true</value>
  </property>
   <property>
       <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
       <value>true</value>
   </property>
```

The property name I'm triying is :

```
 <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.inputformat.class</name
     <value>org.lab41.dendrite.generator.kronecker.mapreduce.lib.input.QuotaInputFormat</value>
  </property>
```

Is the correct property name?

Answer (score 1):

you can see this page
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Map+Reduce+Cookbook

correct property name should be 'mapred.input.format.class'

so, you can write like this :

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.input.format.class</name>
    <value>org.lab41.dendrite.generator.kronecker.mapreduce.lib.input.QuotaInputFormat</value>
</property>
```