# MapReduce job failed in oozie

Tags: mapreduce, oozie

I've a map only job which takes sequence file (key is Text, value is BytesWritable) as input and output data in to sequence  file (key is NullWritable, value is Text).

**Java class**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Test");

        job.setJarByClass(Test.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TestMapper.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.submit();
    }

    public static class TestMapper extends Mapper<Text, BytesWritable, NullWritable, Text> {
        Text outValue = new Text("");
        int counter = 0;
        public void map(Text filename, BytesWritable data, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        / logic
              }
    }
}
```

It's working fine when running job from unix command, when the same job scheduled in oozie seeing below error

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
at Test$TestMapper.map(Test.java:56)

job configuration in oozie

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.input.dir</name>
<value>${input}</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.output.dir</name>
<value>/temp</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
<value>Test$TestMapper</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
<value>0</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.output.key.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.output.value.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.inputformat.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.outputformat.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.mapinput.key.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.mapinput.value.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
```

Can someone tell me what is the error here.. thank you

Comment: Possible replicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184297/ozzie-inputformat-mapreduce-api. Try using the config value mapred.input.format.class

Comment: thanks for the reply, didn't work for me...  <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.format.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat</value>
                </property>

Comment: what about mapreduce.inputformat.class?

Comment: it's working fine with   <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.inputformat.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat</value>
                </property>.. thanks you :)

Comment: Ok I will add an answer since it is not the same answer as the previously linked question.

Answer (score 1):

The classcast exception indicates that Oozie is still using the default inputformat of TextInputFormat, which has a Key type of LongWritable. Since the mapper has a key type of Text, there is a type mismatch on ingestion by the mapper. So the config key of mapreduce.job.inputformat.class was incorrect.

(after some trial and error)

We found that the correct property name is mapreduce.inputformat.class, i.e.:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.inputformat.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat</value>
</property>
```